# Probability and logical quantifiers

Tags: probability, logic

I'm trying to show

$$\mathop{\forall}_{\epsilon>0} \mathop{\exists}_{C>0} \mathbb{P}\left(f(0)>a_C\right)<\epsilon.$$

I can construct an event $\Omega$ such that $\mathbb{P}(\Omega)\geq1-\epsilon$ and

$$\omega \in \Omega \implies \mathop{\exists}_{C>0} f(0) \leq a_C. $$

Is the result obvious just from this? It makes sense since for small values of $\epsilon$, the event $\Omega$ has a large probability, and the consequent of the implication cannot have a smaller probability than its antecedent. However, the quantifier $\exists$ is causing me some problems. I tried to write some extra steps and argued as follows.

From the contrapositive of the implication, I get that

$$\mathop{\forall}_{C>0} f(0)>a_C \implies  \omega\notin \Omega,$$

so that

$$\mathbb{P} \left(\mathop{\forall}_{C>0} f(0)>a_C\right) \leq \mathbb{P(\bar{\Omega})} <\epsilon,$$
where $\bar{\Omega}$ is the complement of $\Omega,$ but that last line looks strange. If I take the probability inside the $\forall$ operator, I end up with something stronger than I hoped for and it doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have an event $\Omega$ such that $\mathbb{P}(\Omega) \geq 1-\epsilon$ and $\omega \in \omega \Rightarrow (\exists C>0) (f(0) \leq a_C)$, then you've shown $\mathbb{P}\Big((\exists C>0) (f(0)>a_C )\Big) < \epsilon$. However, you wanted to show $(\exists C>0)(\mathbb{P}(f(0)>a_C)<\epsilon)$. I'll show that these are not the same.

To simplify things, notice you essentially have statements of the form $\mathbb{P}\Big((\exists k)Q(k)\Big)<\epsilon$ and $(\exists k)(\mathbb{P}(Q(k))<\epsilon)$. Let $X_0=0$ and $X_1=1$. Let $Q(k)=\{X_k=0\}$ for $k=0,1$. Then for any $0<\epsilon<1$,
$$(\exists k)(\mathbb{P}(Q(k))<\epsilon) \text{ is true}$$
because $\mathbb{P}(Q(1))=\mathbb{P}(X_1=0)=0<\epsilon$. However,
$$\mathbb{P}\Big((\exists k)Q(k)\Big)<\epsilon \text{ is false}$$
because $\mathbb{P}\Big((\exists k)Q(k)\Big)=1$ as $Q(0)$ is true.

Comment: Got it! I see the difference.